# Win10 / Pyinstaller ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pyinstaller

**Summary**

I just wrote a Python (3.7.2) program and an using Pyinstaller (3.4) to compile it to an exe. The Python file is using opencv-python (which required numpy) as a dependency. Despite having looked for a while, none of the solutions I have seen online have worked for me.

I do not have anaconda installed, not do I have multiple versions of any of the libs I am using (including Python itself).

Also, when I run 'from numpy import multiarray' in python, even that prints out an error that it cannot do the import.

**What I have tried**

unistalling and reinstalling numpy and opencv-python

updating numpy to the latest version (1.16).

Running pyinstaller on the program in Windows 10 and 7 VMs in addition to my native Windows 10 (with all dependencies installed prior via pip, of course) (A quick note--when I ran on Win7 I did not get any of the 'lib not found:' errors that I saw in Win10, but the program still failed to run)

None of these results made a difference in the error message I received that 
'numpy.core.multiarray failed to import'.

**The question**

How do I get my program to compile to an exe? I'm open to using a different program (other than pyinstaller).

Thank you!!

**The data I have**

**Here is the error message from running 'from numpy import multiarray' in a python terminal:**

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray' from 'numpy' (C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py)
```

**Here is the full error message from attempting to run the compiled exe**

```
PS C:\Users\name\Downloads\py\dist\SignRecorder> .\SignRecorder.exe
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "SignRecorder.py", line 1, in <module>
File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
[15208] Failed to execute script SignRecorder
```

**Here is the final build output from pyinstaller**

```
C:\Users\name\Downloads\py\build\SignRecorder\SignRecorder.exe
19881 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
19893 INFO: checking COLLECT
19893 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
19894 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
28366 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Comment: It is quite possible that you have another version of _numpy_ installed somewhere on your computer that is causing this problem. You might want to check that. Or you could try uninstalling the version you have and then installing a version below the latest available.

Comment: How would I check for that? I tried running 'pip list' and it only showed one numpy version. Also, running 'pip uninistall numpy' multiple times only removes numpy once, so I do not know where my other numpys would be.

Comment: Did you use a virtual environnent ? It may solve your issue if you run pyinstaller in this isolated and controled env.

Comment: I did not use a virtual environment. I can try using venv and see it it helps later today

Comment: I used venv to create a virtual environment and still got the same error: (I did remember to activate the environment)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray' from 'numpy' (C:\Users\name\Documents\Standard Documents\Programming\Environments\SignRecorderEnvironment\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py)

Comment: This could be an issue with the latest numpy and pyinstaller. Did you try using older, _working_ numpy versions instead?

Comment: I had tried that, but it was not just numpy that waws the problem. I had to go back to Python3.5 with Pyinstaller 3.4 and numpy 1.15 to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Rick M, I was able to find out that my versions were too recent and did not work well with each other. The configuration I used that worked was:

Python 3.5 or 3.7.2 (latest as of 01 / 23 / 2019)

Pyinstaller 3.4

numpy 1.15

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I faced this issue recently with Python `3.8.10`, numpy `1.24.4`, and pyinstaller `6.1.0` so I hope I can help others who are also facing the same issue.

My solution was to explicitly import numpy on the main file that I am converting to exe (otherwise, numpy would be imported by another library that I explicitly import). So just include in your code:

```
import numpy as np
```

Then pyinstaller should be able to detect it. Hopefully this helps.

Edit: I couldn't downgrade my numpy because one of the libraries that I was using requires that version of numpy